# How to create bootstrap based steps progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to a linear progress bar with circles indicating steps for showing the users progress as shown in the image below:

[image: circle based lines].

I will have 7 pages in total.
So the pages will be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6

I make 1 progress bar but it does not depends on pages , I want some thing like when user click on next button in the page then it redirects to another page and progress bar shows step 2 and similar for all 7 pages

Below is the code I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
  $('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');

    $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

    $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');

    $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').addClass('active');

    $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 2) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

    i++;

    if (i == 0) {
      $('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
      $('.progress div.circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
      i = 1;
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.progress {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
}
.progress .bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 6px;
  top: -33px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.progress .circle .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
/* Done / Active */

.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
  background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #66cccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
  color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0c95be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
  color: #0c95be;
}
.bar.done {
  background: #66cccc !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done">
    <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">0%</span>
  </div>
  <span class="bar done"></span>
  <div class="circle done">
    <span class="label">2</span>
    <span class="title">25%</span>
  </div>
  <span class="bar half"></span>
  <div class="circle active">
    <span class="label">3</span>
    <span class="title">50%</span>
  </div>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">4</span>
    <span class="title">75%</span>
  </div>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">5</span>
    <span class="title">100%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added my code please help me now

Comment: @user3784723 Since you are redirecting to new pages why can't you just hard code the state of circle in each page? For example the code in first page always displays the first circle, second page always displays the second circle and so on... You can even use static images... What is the problem with that?

Comment: Actually i want to display half portion between step1 and step2 when i am on the second page and i need it by css.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can display half portion of the bar by splitting the current `span.bar` element into two elements with half the size.

For example:

```
.progress .bar-half {
  width: 40px;
}
<span class="bar bar-half done"></span>
<span class="bar bar-half"></span>
```

Then you can indicate progress by adding the class `done` to the respective bar.

So in your case, you can simply setup the progressbar with static progress in each of your HTML pages.

below is an example with half filled bar:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.progress {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
}
.progress .bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 6px;
  top: -33px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.progress .bar-half {
  width: 40px;
}
.progress .circle .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
/* Done / Active */

.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
  background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #66cccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
  color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0c95be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
  color: #0c95be;
}
.bar.done {
  background: #66cccc !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done">
    <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">0%</span>
  </div>
  <span class="bar bar-half done"></span>
  <span class="bar bar-half"></span>
  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">2</span>
    <span class="title">25%</span>
  </div>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">3</span>
    <span class="title">50%</span>
  </div>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">4</span>
    <span class="title">75%</span>
  </div>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">5</span>
    <span class="title">100%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```